# Disable autoscrolling in gnome 3.4

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, scrolling

I've recently updated my gnome to 3.4 and a problem appears.

When I start scrolling, scroll never ends and even continues to scroll when I switch to another window.

How can I disable this annoying feature?

I run gnome on ArchLinux with kernel 3.3

Comment: Doesn't sound like a feature...considered [filing a bug report](http://bugs.gnome.org)? ([Maybe there is one already.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=auto-scroll)) -- If you used Arch's packages, maybe [this is the place to go.](https://bugs.archlinux.org/)

Comment: It is certainly a bug, but seems like the auto-scrolling feature has been added to gnome 3.4, so maybe there is an option to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it was a problem with the synaptics touchpad driver. I've installed gsynaptics and unchecked the continue scrolling checkbox in the Scrolling tab, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution without installing that software:

- edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf`
- add the line

  ```
  Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
  ```

I'm also having some problems scrolling in nautilus. Scrolling is not working on folders either in dconf-editor for instance.

Comment: I have the same problem. It works sometimes though (very rarely)...